# Can the user modify the information available in the claims?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, claims

I have an ASP .NET MVC project using Azure Active Directory for Authentication and I would like to store information in the claims (ClaimsIdentity) like a custom UserId.
I would then want to retrieve the custom UserId from the claims to check if user is authorized to access some page.

Where are these custom claims being stored? Would the user be able to modify the values in the claims?

Answer (score 0):

It is common in most back end apps to need to use tokens from multiple places:

- OAuth token claims
- Product claims

In MVC there is usually an OnTokenValidated method you can override to customise the claims identity with product claims, as in [this article](https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2).

The custom claims are then carried around in an HTTP only / encrypted authentication cookie.